# Webcomic about flying ships and teens in WW2

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

Does anybody remember a webcomic with flying ships that act like battleships, world leaders talk to cats or panthers who are spiritual guides, teens fighting a war that looks like world war 2... but with big flying birds on one side and technology and big flying battleships at the other?

Comment: How long ago did you read this?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is probably [Alpha Shade](http://www.alpha-shade.com/0Comics/pages.php).  It was a pretty well-done comic, decent art quality, reasonable depth in the story, but it [ran out of steam pretty quickly](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/AlphaShade).

It's more World War I technology than WW2, except for a scene set in a more advanced world (equivalent to current Earth) where two of the cast are playing a MMO war game.

[image: sandbagged howitzers] [image: biplanes]

The side that has the biplanes has deployed from flying ships:

[image: Ships unloading]

The biplanes are fighting an enemy that mounts giant feathered fliers.

[image: giant fliers on patrol]

There are telepathic cats that may be panthers that act as leaders or advisors (they are addressed as "Lord" by lower classes, but treated by leaders as equals).

[image: Grey in command]  [image: panthers in command] [image: memory of panthers, showing as cat]